# log form persisted data with LoggerInterface

Tags: php, symfony, logging

In my Symfony project I want to log the data I get from my form so I can keep track what is edited.

```
$data = $form->getData();
```

When `dump()` that result I get: [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HORQw.png)

I want to pass that data in within my logger.

I use  `Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;`

```
$this->logger->info("User {$data->getFirstName()} edited:", [
            'fields' => $data
        ]);
```

and in my `dev.log` I get:

```
[2022-02-23 10:40:21] app.INFO: User John edited: {"fields":[]} []
```

I tried using get_object_vars() and it still returns empty array.
I want to avoid using `$data->getFirstName, $data->getLastName()` etc. to construct this.

Answer (score 0):

I propose you to use the function `get_object_vars` inside your class object, bellow an example :

```
class User {
   ...
   ...

    public function toArray()
    {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }

   ...
   ...
}
```

To understand, the function `get_object_vars` can't accesss to private properties outside object.

Finally, you can do :

```
    $this->logger->info("User {$data->getFirstName()} edited:", [
        'fields' => $data->toArray()
    ]);
```